# Perl Net::SSH2::Cisco timeout on read when sending cmd() to switch

Tags: perl

Basically I have Cisco and Dell switches that I am trying to access using [Net::SSH2::Cisco](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2::Cisco) but I am getting a weird timeout error. Here is the code that is running:

```
     $swConn = Net::SSH2::Cisco->new(Host => "$switchname.something", Prompt =>  '/' . $switch .'#/') or push(@skipFailedSwitches, $switch);

##############################################################################
# Changes for Cisco Nexus 5020 Switch start here
#
# Included the code for varying the password depending on switch
##############################################################################


    $password = #mypassword;


  print "logging into $switchname.something  with username $username and password $password \n"; #SBW

  if (not $swConn->login($username, $password)){
    push(@skipFailedSwitches, $switch);
    next;
  }
  #$swConn->login(Password => #mypassword);
#$fh = $swConn->input_log();
##############################################################################
# Changes for Cisco Nexus 5020 Switch end here
#
##############################################################################
$swConn->cmd('terminal length 0') or push(@skipFailedSwitches, $switch);
my @statusOut = $swConn->cmd('show interface status') or push(@skipFailedSwitches, $switch);
```

This gives me

> timed-out during read at ./etherShine.pl line 172

Line 172 is

```
$swConn->cmd('terminal length 0') or push(@skipFailedSwitches, $switch);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question and include the actual error, with line number. Also tell us what line in the code you're showing us that is.

Comment: Ok hopefully that made it more clear. Thanks for giving me the tips.

Comment: So without knowing that module, it seems like your connection is actually timing out. Did this work before? Have you made changes to your network?

Comment: It worked when I used Net::Telnet::Cisco. I needed to switch to a different module since we just recently got Dell switches. I find it weird that its able to log in (to my understanding) but times out when sending a cmd. My knowledge of switches is very limited.